# Spectral resolution of multiplication operator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Kosaku YOSIDA claims in his book "Functional Analysis" that it is easy to see that the multiplication operator

$Hx(t) = tx(t)$ in $L^2(-\infty,+\infty)$

admits the spectral resolution $H = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lambda \, \mathrm{d}E(\lambda)$, where the resolution of the identity is defined via

$E(\lambda)x(t) = x(t)$ for $t \leq \lambda$,
$=0$ for $t > \lambda$.

At this point in the book (Chapter XI.6 Normed Rings and Spectral Representation: The Spectral Resolution of a Self-adjoint Operator) the Spectral theorem is NOT yet proven.

---

I have problemes with the "easy to see"-part. I think he tries to argue that
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lambda^2 \, \mathrm{d} \| E(\lambda) x \|^2 = \|Hx\|^2$
and
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \, \mathrm{d} \langle E(\lambda) x , y \rangle = \langle Hx, y \rangle$.

But how does this show the claim?

Comment: What you have to show (by the usual definition) is $\int \lambda d\langle E(\lambda) x, y\rangle = \langle H x, y\rangle$ for all $x,y$ (as well as $\int d\langle E(\lambda)x, y\rangle = \langle x, y\rangle$).

Comment: As far as I know only the first identity is needed according to the definition. Where is the second one needed?

Comment: This expresses the fact that $E$ is indeed a resolution of the identity. I don't know whether this follows automatically.

Comment: I have just "manually" shown this fact. So the first identity should suffice. I wonder why Yosida has also shown that $\int \lambda^2 \, \mathrm{d} \| E(\lambda)x \|^2 = \|Hx\|^2$ holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\rho$ is a bounded measurable function on $[a,b]$, then $E(t)=\int_{a}^{t}\rho(u)du$ is a function of bounded variation and, for any continuous function $g$,
$$
             \int_{a}^{b}g(t)dE(t) = \int_{a}^{b}g(t)\frac{dE}{dt}dt = \int_{a}^{b}g(t)\rho(t)dt.
$$
In your case,
$$
          \|E(t)x\|^{2}=\int_{-\infty}^{t}|x(u)|^{2}du 
$$
The above easily extends to
\begin{align}
         \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^{2}d\|E(t)x\|^{2} & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^{2}\frac{d\|E(t)x\|^{2}}{dt}dt \\ &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}t^{2}|x(t)|^{2}dt = \|Hx\|^{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Don't we rather need to show $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lambda \, \mathrm{d} \langle E(\lambda) x, y \rangle = \langle Hx, y \rangle$ for all $x,y$?

Comment: @R.Swan : I gave you the first of the two. The second one is proved in the same way.

Comment: @R.Swan : $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda d_{\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda}x(t)\overline{y(t)}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda \frac{d}{d\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda}x(t)\overline{y(t)}dt d\lambda = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lambda f(\lambda)\overline{g(\lambda)}d\lambda = (Hf,g)$.

Comment: Thank you. I have two questions: (1) What kind of notation ist $\mathrm{d}_\lambda $? I have never seen that. (2) Why do we need two identities? Is it soley to prove that E ist a resolution of the identity?

Comment: (3) I am also having troubles understanding the formal manipulations of the differentials (i.e. kind of treating them as fractions)

Comment: @R.Swan : This is a classical work, and I'm using a classical interpretation as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)d\rho(t)$, though you can elevate this to Lebesgue-Stietljes with no serious issues. When I write $d_{\lambda}$, I am just reminding you that the variable of integration is $\lambda$. If $\rho$ is absolutely continuous and $f$ is continuous, then the Riemann Stieltjes integral of $f$ with respect to $\rho$ is $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)d\rho(t) = \int_{a}^{b}f(t)\rho'(t)dt = \int_{a}^{b}f(t)\frac{d\rho(t)}{dt}dt$. It looks like manipulation of symbols, but it's not.

Comment: That makes sense. In my case $\rho(\lambda) = \int_{-\infty}^{\lambda} x(t) \overline{y(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t$. As this equals $\langle E(\lambda) x, y \rangle$ we know that $\rho$ is of bounded variation. But how do you know that $\rho$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: @R.Swan : $x(t)\overline{y(t)}$ is absolutely integrable and measurable, which means that $\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda}x(t)\overline{y(t)}dt$ is absolutely continuous in $\lambda$ with derivative equal a.e. to $x(\lambda)\overline{y(\lambda)}$. (This is Lebesgue's differentiation theorem.) Note: absolutely continuous means the function is the integral of its derivative (which, of course, requires the derivative to be locally integrable.)

Comment: Great! Is it also necessary to additionally show $\| Hx \|^2 = \int t^2 \, \mathrm{d} \| E(t) x \|^2$, as you have done in your answer? And if yes, why?

Comment: @R.Swan : The identity for $(Hx,Hx)$ follows from the one for $(Hx,y)$ with $y=Hx$. I had only given you one because the other follows the same pattern. But I decided later to give you the second because you did not seem to be very comfortable with the second one based on the first one only. Takes a bit of getting used to.

Comment: That's a good shortcut. Is the identity for $\langle Hx,Hx\rangle$ needed to show $H=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\lambda\, \mathrm{d} E(\lambda)$? In my opinion it is enough to show the $\langle Hx,y\rangle$ identity. Then $H = \int \lambda \, \mathrm{d} E(\lambda)$ should directly follow, because we have $\left \langle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lambda \, \mathrm{d} E(\lambda)(x) , y \right \rangle = \langle Hx, y \rangle$ for all $x \in D(\int \lambda \, \mathrm{d} E(\lambda))$ (which is dense in $H$) and all $y \in H$. By subtraction the desired equality follows. Maybe I am forgetting something?

Comment: @R.Swan : The part that is probably missing without some careful attention is that $\mathcal{D}(H) = \{ f : \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda^{2}d\|E(\lambda)f\|^{2} < \infty \}$. That's a really important part of the Spectral Theorem.

Comment: Good point, so we actually have shown $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lambda \, \mathrm{d} E(\lambda) \subset H$? Ahhhhh... and with the identity for $(Hx,Hx)$ it follows $D(H) = \{ f: \int \lambda^2 d \| E(\lambda) f \|^2 < \infty \}$, because $\| Hx \|$ never is infinite.

Comment: @R.Swan : With a spectral measure $E$ for an unbounded selfadjoint linear operator $H : \mathcal{D}(H)\subset \mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, part of the statement of the Spectral Theorem is a characterization of the domain as above. And, that condition is equivalent to the convergence of $\int_{a}^{b}\lambda dE(\lambda)f$ as $a\rightarrow-\infty$, $b\rightarrow\infty$. It's a very tight correspondence. However, the form $(Hf,g)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda d(E(\lambda)f,g)$ is not as tight because, as you might suspect, it has more to do with $\sqrt{H}$.

Comment: As far as I see it, Yosida has not proven that "reverse" part of the spectral theorem at this point in his book. He has however established that for a given resolution of the identity $E$ there exists a self-adjoint operator, denoted by $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lambda \, \mathrm{d} E(\lambda)$ with $D \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lambda \, \mathrm{d} E(\lambda) \right) = \{ f : \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\lambda|^2 \, \mathrm{d} \| E(\lambda f \|^2 < \infty \}$. If we can show that $D(H)$ is exactely this set, we are finished. And this set-equality is shown by calculating $(Hx,Hx)$

Comment: @R.Swan - Your statement looks correct. I don't think there is anything remaining for this problem, is there?